# getElementsByClassName issue when i want to make for another form

Tags: javascript, dom

Recently, I have asked a question about confirm and it's solved but the problem now is the code was for ids only when I try to make for classes it changed only for the first form and not for a second.

```js
function fuelPrice()
{
    var fuelPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["price"];
    var withFuelPrice = document.getElementsByClassName("ful");
    if(withFuelPrice[0].checked==true)
    {
        fuelPrice=30;
    }
    return fuelPrice;
}

function withPol()
{
    var polishPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["price"];
    var includeInscription = document.getElementsByClassName("pol");
    if(includeInscription[0].checked==true){
        polishPrice=50;
    }
    return polishPrice;
}

function driver()
{
    var driverPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["price"];
    var getDriv = document.getElementsByClassName("drv");
    if(getDriv[0].checked==true){
        driverPrice=50;
    }
    return driverPrice;
}

function calculateTotal()
{
var car1= 50
    var total = fuelPrice() + withPol() + car1 + driver();
     var text = "Total Price For the Renting "+total+ "BHD/Week";
    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementsByClassName('totalPrice');
    divobj[0].style.display='block';
    divobj[0].innerHTML = text;
  
    return text;

}

function myFunction()
{
 var name = calculateTotal()
 confirm(name)
}
```

```html
    <form class="price"><p class="totalPrice booktxt">Total Price For the Renting 50BHD/Week<br> </p>
                <input onclick="calculateTotal() " type="checkbox" class="ful">With Fuel<br>
                <input onclick="calculateTotal() " type="checkbox" class="pol">Polishing 2 weeks<br>
                <input onclick="calculateTotal() " type="checkbox" class="drv">Driver<br>

                </form>
            <button class="btn1" onclick="myFunction()">Add to cart</button>



<form class="price"><p class="totalPrice booktxt">Total Price For the Renting 50BHD/Week<br> </p>
                <input onclick="calculateTotal() " type="checkbox" class="ful">With Fuel<br>
                <input onclick="calculateTotal() " type="checkbox" class="pol">Polishing 2 weeks<br>
                <input onclick="calculateTotal() " type="checkbox" class="drv">Driver<br>

                </form>
            <button class="btn1" onclick="myFunction()">Add to cart</button>
```

Comment: That's because you are always accessing the first element in the list of elements: `withFuelPrice[0]`, `getDriv[0]`, etc.

Comment: so I need to do loop right, I will post my loop by the way i am still beginner

Comment: @SayedHasan if you don't want to do a loop check my answer. If you want dynamic function tellme and i can edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

See if i understand...

You should to separate the forms. Check this code...

```js
function fuelPrice(form)
{
    var fuelPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["price"];
    var withFuelPrice = document.getElementsByClassName("ful");
    if(withFuelPrice[form].checked==true)
    {
        fuelPrice=30;
    }
    return fuelPrice;
}

function withPol(form)
{
    var polishPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["price"];
    var includeInscription = document.getElementsByClassName("pol");
    if(includeInscription[form].checked==true){
        polishPrice=50;
    }
    return polishPrice;
}

function driver(form)
{
    var driverPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["price"];
    var getDriv = document.getElementsByClassName("drv");
    if(getDriv[form].checked==true){
        driverPrice=50;
    }
    return driverPrice;
}

function calculateTotal(form)
{
var car1= 50
    var total = fuelPrice(form) + withPol(form) + car1 + driver(form);
     var text = "Total Price For the Renting "+total+ "BHD/Week";
    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementsByClassName('totalPrice');
    divobj[form].style.display='block';
    divobj[form].innerHTML = text;
  
    return text;

}

function myFunction()
{
 var name = calculateTotal()
 confirm(name)
}
```

```html
<form class="price"><p class="totalPrice booktxt">Total Price For the Renting 50BHD/Week<br> </p>
                <input onclick="calculateTotal(0) " type="checkbox" class="ful">With Fuel<br>
                <input onclick="calculateTotal(0) " type="checkbox" class="pol">Polishing 2 weeks<br>
                <input onclick="calculateTotal(0) " type="checkbox" class="drv">Driver<br>

                </form>



<form class="price"><p class="totalPrice booktxt">Total Price For the Renting 50BHD/Week<br> </p>
                <input onclick="calculateTotal(1) " type="checkbox" class="ful">With Fuel<br>
                <input onclick="calculateTotal(1) " type="checkbox" class="pol">Polishing 2 weeks<br>
                <input onclick="calculateTotal(1) " type="checkbox" class="drv">Driver<br>

                </form>
```

Comment: yes it worked, but the calculation is done in one confirm function so, I need to make loop or copy and paste